# Accessing Slider.Thumb events

Tags: c#, wpf, slider

I am trying to use the thumb.DragCompleted and thumb.DragStarted events. But Non of the examples I have found on the internet work!? when I add a slider control there is not "Thumb" field, nor do I have a "Thumb" control.

```
<Slider x:Name="slider" Thumb  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

`slider.Thumb`

Thumb is not recognized or accessible. The slider itself does not have a dragstarted or dragcompleted event. All of the examples just access the thumb field in XAML or in C# and I simply get an error!? Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Those are [routed events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7) you can handle on the `Slider`, which contains a `Thumb` inside its `ControlTemplate`. Thus there simply is no `Thumb` property because it's not defined on the `Slider` itself.